# Handle shake gesture within SKScene

Tags: cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I am experimenting with SpriteKite and it is handling touch events perfectly.
How can I implement a shake event? I assume I am failing the set the first responder correctly within the scene/when the scene is presented.

code within SKScene that is never called.

```
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake ) {
        [self shakeEvent];
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you set your SKScene as a listener for the shake gesture?

Comment: I have experimented with the below and trying to set [self becomeFirstResponder]; at various points in SKScene (during init etc.), but couldn't make it work. Implementing the shake event within the ViewController that loads the SKScene worked, but I was unable to find a way to call shakeEvent from outside an already presented SKScene. 

    - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
   
        return YES;
     
    }

Comment: If you have succeeded in solving this problem, add the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may post a notification from the ViewController and add an observer to the SKScene.